# setting temp array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Is it legal to set a temporary local array like this

```
NSArray *valueArray = [slide componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

Where slide is a string?
or do I have to init and release?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem, since that method returns an autoreleased `NSArray`, it's the autorelease pool's job to release it when necessary. There's no other administrative work you need to do: no `alloc init` or manual `release`.